# Perl memcached connections not evenly distributed across nodes

Tags: perl, memcached

We have an Elasticache Memcached cluster which is being used by a legacy perl application.

The nodes are defined like so...

```
my @cache_nodes = (
    {
        address => '[node1 address]:11211',
        weight  => 1,
    },
    {
        address => '[node2 address]:11211',
        weight  => 1,
    },
    {
        address => '[node3 address]:11211',
        weight  => 1,
    },
);
```

Memcached Fast is then initialised like so...

```
my $cache_namespace = 'my_namespace::';
my $cache = new Cache::Memcached::Fast({
  servers => \@cache_nodes,
    namespace => $cache_namespace,
    utf8 => 1
});
```

I can see that all nodes are being used, and the cache item count is evenly distributed between the nodes.

However for some reason the actual connections vary signficantly across the nodes. Under load, node3 may have 3x the number of "current connections" as node1.

Also there is a fairly significant variation with the hit and miss counts across the 3 nodes.

I would expect, since the items are distributed evenly, that connections and hits should also be evenly distributed.

Can anyone suggest why this might not be the case?

Comment: Perhaps the application like's one key/val in particular.  This could lead to the usage pattern that you're observing.  I'd suggest isolating this to a unit test with random data and see if you're still seeing the uneven distribution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241807/why-memcached-does-not-synchronize-across-nodes might be informative in telling why cache entries are stored the way they are